# How to feed iptables rules with a list of ip addresses on a text file

Tags: networking, iptables, firewall

Is there a module where i can feed `iptables` rules with ip addresses from a plain text file?

Example: I have a generated by `iptables-restore` custom ruleset with the following custom chain to allow WhatsApp related ip addresses:

```
    :_WHATSAPP_ - [0:0]
    -A _WHATSAPP_ -j ACCEPT
    -A FORWARD -s <src_host> -d 31.13.64.51/32 -j _WHATSAPP_
    -A FORWARD -s <src_host> -d 31.13.65.49/32 -j _WHATSAPP_
    -A FORWARD -s <src_host> -d 31.13.66.49/32 -j _WHATSAPP_
    -A FORWARD -s <src_host> -d 31.13.67.51/32 -j _WHATSAPP_
    -A FORWARD -s <src_host> -d 31.13.68.52/32 -j _WHATSAPP_
    -A FORWARD -s <src_host> -d 31.13.69.240/32 -j _WHATSAPP_
    ----snip-----
```

All ip addresses used by WhatsApp can be found at [this link](https://www.whatsapp.com/cidr.txt).

It would be way faster from time to time download this file, filter ipv4 addresses and use a switch(if exists) that could feed iptables with this information like:

```
    :_WHATSAPP_ - [0:0]
    -A _WHATSAPP_ -j ACCEPT
    -A FORWARD -s <src_host> --from-file-dst /etc/iptables/whatsapp_cidr.txt -j _WHATSAPP_
```

Does this feature exists? Could not find it on manpages.

It needs to be some module that could load and read files, since we have a custom firewall script that already deals with a file using `iptables-restore` sintax rules.

Answer (score 1):

I could suggest a way to feed `iptables` with list of `IPs` by using `ipset`.

you can simply create and `ipset`:

```
ipset -N <ipset name> iphash
```

then you can add any `IP` to the set using:

```
ipset add <ipset name> IP
```

after that you can use the set in `iptables`:

```
-A FORWARD -d <dst> -m set --match-set <ipset name> src -j _WHATSAPP_
```

You can write a simple script that can feed the set with `IPs` and delete from it on the run time without need to make `iptables-restore`

Comment: Can't use `ipset` cause there is a custom script that will read only this file with rules inside, formated as `iptables-restore`... And this script is somehow a "legacy stuff written in python" that will take too much time to deal with  :(

Answer (score 0):

I think a good Idea may be using this https://gist.github.com/woods/25ef91a95da85bf10974
Then you create a separate .csv file with IP's and feed it to IPTABLES

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).